# Where to destroy database instance: Activity onDestroy() or ViewModel onCleared()?

Tags: android, memory-management, viewmodel, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

Where should I destroy my database instance? `onDestroy()` in the Activity or `onCleared()` in its ViewModel?

I've implemented it in my Activity `onDestroy()` method:

```java
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // if activity being destroyed is not because of config change...
    if (isFinishing()) {
        AppDatabase.destroyInstance();
    }
}
```

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#ondestroy) seems to suggest that this should be done in the `onCleared()` callback of the ViewModel. What if I use the same ViewModel for example for the activity and its fragment? Then the `onCleared()` method is called twice (for each instance of the ViewModel).

Comment: Why do you need to destroy the instance? What class is this an instance of?

Comment: @DavidWasser it's Room database: `public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {...}`. I do not know why should I destroy it, I've seen that in [code examples](https://medium.com/@magdamiu/android-room-persistence-library-97ad0d25668e#288f)

Comment: This method just sets the reference to the database to `null` to allow the garbage collector to reclaim it. Where are you creating the database?

Comment: In the class `AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase...` with the first call to `getDatabase()` from a Repository

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is fine. When your `Activity` is destroyed you can release the database resources.